# SharePoint 2013 - Swapping CSS files with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

On my SP 2013 Master Page, I want to click a button and change the path to the style sheets. Not sure if it's a path issue or what... but it's not changing the style sheets.

My style sheets are stored in the Style Library/css folder.

`alert($(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');` tells me that the click function are working per button.

**JavaScript on Master page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        console.log("working...");
        $('#style1').click(function (){
            //alert($(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');
           $('link[href="http://khsp.cloudapp.net/Style Library/css/DT_Override_main_style2"]').attr('href',"http://khsp.cloudapp.net/Style Library/css/DT_Override_main_style1");
        });
        $('#style2').click(function (){
            //alert($(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');
           $('link[href="http://khsp.cloudapp.net/Style Library/css/DT_Override_main_style1"]').attr('href',"http://khsp.cloudapp.net/Style Library/css/DT_Override_main_style2");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML on Master page:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-5">
        <button type="button" id="style1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">
             <span class="ui-button-text">Style 1</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">
        <button type="button" id="style2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Style 2</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: looks fine to me. what is it doing right now? is it refreshing the page? does it just sit there without doing anything? use `console.log` to see if those link selectors are correct.

Comment: @Krishna It's not refreshing the page or anything... but when I add in `alert($(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');` it outputs the appropriate button ID. How can I use console.log to check the selectors?

Comment: what does `alert($('link[href="http://khsp.cloudapp.net/Style Library/css/DT_Override_main_style1"]').length)` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y2Eb/). Use an ID on the link tag but you may need to tweak it because SP is generating a client ID from `#styleSheet` to `#ctl00_styleSheet` on my VM. You can see in the console that the href of the link is changing with the clicks.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp `id` is not a valid parameter for `link`: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

Comment: [W3 Schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) is not a reliable resource. Better documentation is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) and for HTML5 the ID attribute is valid for all elements.